# How can I execute all commands in crontab subsequently?

Tags: linux, bash, script, cron, crontab

Consider a complicated crontab of +100 lines where a lot of scripts are run subsequently to poll & process messages from different clients.

Upon reboot of the server, I trigger some scripts of the most important clients to run immediately (copy / paste).

However, a one-liner to process all crontab-entries would greatly help.

All scripts reside in /opt/, so all lines look like:

```
m h  dom mon dow     /opt/XXXXXX/YYYYY/ZZZZZ.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

In m, h & dow "/" & "-" are also sometimes used, f.e. :

```
*/3 5-21 * * 1-5     /opt/XXXXXX/YYYYY/ZZZZZ.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 0-1,5-23 * * *   /opt/XXXXXX/YYYYY/ZZZZZ.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
25 2 * * 7           /opt/XXXXXX/YYYYY/ZZZZZ.sh >/dev/null 2>&1

crontab -l | grep -v "#" | wc -l
129
```

T.I.A.
Jord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the makings of an answer in your question.

If you modify your `crontab` line to:

```
crontab -l | grep -v "#" | grep -o '/opt/.*$' > cron.tmp
```

then `cron.tmp` will contain all the commands you need to run. You can run it as is with `. ./cron.tmp`, or you can make it executable and run it direct with `chmod +x cron.tmp && ./cron.tmp`.

If you want to avoid a temporary file, you can use:

```
crontab -l | grep -v "#" | grep -o '/opt/.*$' | while read l; do eval $l; done
```

You need to use `eval` so that the redirections in the commands will be acted on.

Note that you could combine the two `grep` runs into a single `sed` substitution:

```
crontab -l | sed -n 's=^[^#]*\(/opt/.*$\)=\1=p' | while read l; do echo eval $l; done
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.... Thanks! Modified slightly to see what's happening:    `crontab -l | grep -v "#" | grep -o '/opt/.*$' | while read l; do eval $l && echo $l && sleep 2; done`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the [run-parts command](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-run-parts/),
which takes a directory as parameter and will run every executable or script
in this directory.

For example :

```
run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, a one-liner to process all crontab-entries would greatly help.

Make a script that does this, then call it from `cron`'s `@reboot`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for script in /opt/XXXXXX/YYYYY/*.sh; do
 $script
 done
```

If you have to recurse directories:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /opt/XXXXXX/ -name '*.sh' -type f -exec '{}' \;
```

Only have certain scripts you want to run, but a bunch of them?

Do this for each such script:

```
ln -s /opt/XXXXXX/YYYYY/whatever.sh /opt/run-at-reboot/
```

Then call this from `cron`'s `@reboot`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for script in /opt/run-at-reboot/*.sh; do
 $script
 done
```